# How to authenticate and authorize in GitHub Actions chains of module source calls

Tags: authorization, github-actions

I have 3 private repositories (A, B, C) with 2fa. I'm a user in the organization but I don't own it.
I have the following chain of module calls in Terraform:

```
Repo A
--main.tf
---module "client" { source = "github.com/myorg/RepoB//"

Repo B
--main.tf
---module "databases" { source = "github.com/myorg/RepoC//"
```

When I run "terraform init" locally, I get prompted for the private key for my ssh keyfile for use for each of the repositories, in other words 3 times and everything works.

When I try to execute that chain in GitHub actions, the error message is:

```
Could not download module ... fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com'
```

I then changed all my references to modules from "github.com/myorg/RepoC//" to "git::ssh://myorg@github.com/RepoC//" and installed the ssh keys on the runner first via knowhosts and id_res files and later via sshagent. The error on the GitHub Action runner was:

```
Cloning into '.terraform/modules/client_instance'...
│ myorg@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
│ fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I attempted to run that locally, I didn't get prompted and it just failed with permission denied (public key)

My questions are:

1. what is the correct or preferred way to refer to modules in other repositories, even when they are in the same organization.
2. how should the handling of ssh keys be accomplished. I tried deployment keys but may have misunderstood their use. When I set up deployment keys, I gave the repo A the private portion of the key and the repo B the public portion of the key assuming that the repo B will want to know whether repo A is authorized. That failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Terraform / Module Sources / GitHub](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#github), you should use an SSH URL

```
source = "git@github.com:myorg/RepoB.git"
```

(Trailing '/' should not be needed)

Now, regarding the SSH keys and GitHub Actions, you can:

1. Generate an SSH key pair if you haven't already.
2. Add the public key to your GitHub account settings.
3. Use the [`webfactory/ssh-agent` action](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) in your GitHub Actions workflow to set up the SSH agent with the private key, which should be stored as a secret in your GitHub repository settings.

Here's the updated sample workflow configuration for your GitHub Actions:

```yaml
name: Terraform

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  terraform:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up SSH agent
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.5.4
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: Set up Terraform
      uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.3.2

    - name: Terraform Init
      run: terraform init
```

Replace `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` with the name of the secret containing your private key.

Comment: Thank you, your answer did the following for me:
1. I realized that I didn't need to deal with Deploy Keys
2. Confirmed that my SSH URL was right, except I had the general version, not the GitHub shortcut.
3. While you described the solution at the level of the first repository being referenced, it applied to all repos called from within that one as well.
4. Indirectly pointed out to me that there must be a place where to store the public portion of the ssh key rather than at my personal profile for this organization so that everyone can use it.
5. It works!